# From a module, consult a file in another module

Tags: module, prolog

For some reason, in my Prolog module I want to be able to consult a file, but like if it was consulted from another module (e.g. *user*).

Say I have a file named `myfile.pl` containing:

```
foo(1).
```

Normally, if in module *mymodule* I execute `consult(myfile)`, what I have is a new predicate `mymodule:foo/1`.

I would like to be able to consult the file from module *mymodule* but the resulting predicate be like `user:foo/1`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried to call `consult(user:myfile)` from within your *mymodule* module?